# Sorting results including null in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to sort some data in date order in JS. This code works apart from the 'null' data. (The null data is where the date field does not exits for that particular result.)  It sits at the top when I need it to sit at the bottom. I have tried various amends but none seem to work. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

```
 if (this.sortBy === "ending") {
            Results.sort((a, b) => {
              if (a.data.t == null || b.data.t == null) {
                return -1;
              }
              let aDate;
              let bDate;
              try {
                aDate = new Date(a.data.t);
              } catch (error) {
                aDate = 99999999;
              }
              try {
                bDate = new Date(b.data.t);
              } catch (error) {
                bDate = 99999999;
              }
    
              if (aDate > bDate) {
                return 1;
              }
              if (aDate < bDate) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            });
          }
    
          return Results;
        },
```

Comment: `new Date` never throws so `try...catch` doesn't do anyhing

Comment: `a.data.t == null || b.data.t == null` - this line works at random, you should instead just check one of them per `if`

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => !a.data.t - !b.data.t || new Date(a.data.t) - new Date(b.data.t) )`

Comment: @adiga Thanks so much. This is the only one which solved my issue!